# How to implement a custom SubtitleDecoderFactory which wraps SubtitleDecoderFactory.DEFAULT, which is a constant instance

Tags: java, interface, instance, constants, wrapper

I am learning Exoplayer, and found a post at https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/4657 (at the end of the post by erdemguven commented on 24 Aug 2018) regarding creating a wrapper SubtitleDecoderFactory which wraps SubtitleDecoderFactory.DEFAULT (at https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/library/core/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/text/SubtitleDecoderFactory.java).

In another post at stackoverflow, I asked a question regarding SubtitleDecoderFactory.DEFAULT, from which I learnt that SubtitleDecoderFactory.DEFAULT is a constant instance. (at [Interface implements overriding its own methods to create an object of itself as DEFAULT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59494282/interface-implements-overriding-its-own-methods-to-create-an-object-of-itself-as))

So here my questions are:

1. Is it neccessary to wrap a constant instance, since the constant instance can be seen and referenced anywhere in the program?
2. If there is a need to wrap this constant instance SubtitleDecoderFactory.DEFAULT, how would the codes be?

This is the base interface SubtitleDecoderFactory (at https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/library/core/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/text/SubtitleDecoderFactory.java):

```
public interface SubtitleDecoderFactory {


  boolean supportsFormat(Format format);


  SubtitleDecoder createDecoder(Format format);


  SubtitleDecoderFactory DEFAULT =
      new SubtitleDecoderFactory() {

        @Override
        public boolean supportsFormat(Format format) {
          @Nullable String mimeType = format.sampleMimeType;
          return MimeTypes.TEXT_VTT.equals(mimeType)
              || MimeTypes.TEXT_SSA.equals(mimeType)
              || MimeTypes.APPLICATION_TTML.equals(mimeType)
              || MimeTypes.APPLICATION_MP4VTT.equals(mimeType)
              || MimeTypes.APPLICATION_SUBRIP.equals(mimeType)
              || MimeTypes.APPLICATION_TX3G.equals(mimeType)
              || MimeTypes.APPLICATION_CEA608.equals(mimeType)
              || MimeTypes.APPLICATION_MP4CEA608.equals(mimeType)
              || MimeTypes.APPLICATION_CEA708.equals(mimeType)
              || MimeTypes.APPLICATION_DVBSUBS.equals(mimeType)
              || MimeTypes.APPLICATION_PGS.equals(mimeType);
        }

        @Override
        public SubtitleDecoder createDecoder(Format format) {
          @Nullable String mimeType = format.sampleMimeType;
          if (mimeType != null) {
            switch (mimeType) {
              case MimeTypes.TEXT_VTT:
                return new WebvttDecoder();
              case MimeTypes.TEXT_SSA:
                return new SsaDecoder(format.initializationData);
              case MimeTypes.APPLICATION_MP4VTT:
                return new Mp4WebvttDecoder();
              case MimeTypes.APPLICATION_TTML:
                return new TtmlDecoder();
              case MimeTypes.APPLICATION_SUBRIP:
                return new SubripDecoder();
              case MimeTypes.APPLICATION_TX3G:
                return new Tx3gDecoder(format.initializationData);
              case MimeTypes.APPLICATION_CEA608:
              case MimeTypes.APPLICATION_MP4CEA608:
                return new Cea608Decoder(mimeType, format.accessibilityChannel);
              case MimeTypes.APPLICATION_CEA708:
                return new Cea708Decoder(format.accessibilityChannel, format.initializationData);
              case MimeTypes.APPLICATION_DVBSUBS:
                return new DvbDecoder(format.initializationData);
              case MimeTypes.APPLICATION_PGS:
                return new PgsDecoder();
              default:
                break;
            }
          }
          throw new IllegalArgumentException(
              "Attempted to create decoder for unsupported MIME type: " + mimeType);
        }
      };
}
```

My custom SubtitleDecoderFactory would look like:

```
public class mSubtitleDecoderFactory implements SubtitleDecoderFactory{

    @Override
    public boolean supportsFormat(Format format) {
        @Nullable String mimeType = format.sampleMimeType;
        return MimeTypes.TEXT_VTT.equals(mimeType)
                || MimeTypes.TEXT_SSA.equals(mimeType)
                || MimeTypes.APPLICATION_TTML.equals(mimeType)
                || MimeTypes.APPLICATION_MP4VTT.equals(mimeType)
                || MimeTypes.APPLICATION_SUBRIP.equals(mimeType)
                || MimeTypes.APPLICATION_TX3G.equals(mimeType)
                || MimeTypes.APPLICATION_CEA608.equals(mimeType)
                || MimeTypes.APPLICATION_MP4CEA608.equals(mimeType)
                || MimeTypes.APPLICATION_CEA708.equals(mimeType)
                || MimeTypes.APPLICATION_DVBSUBS.equals(mimeType)
                || MimeTypes.APPLICATION_PGS.equals(mimeType);
    }

    @Override
    public SubtitleDecoder createDecoder(Format format){

        @Nullable String mimeType = format.sampleMimeType;
        if (mimeType != null) {
            switch (mimeType) {
                case MimeTypes.TEXT_VTT:
                    return new WebvttDecoder();
                case MimeTypes.TEXT_SSA:
                    return new SsaDecoder(format.initializationData);
                case MimeTypes.APPLICATION_MP4VTT:
                    return new Mp4WebvttDecoder();
                case MimeTypes.APPLICATION_TTML:
                    return new TtmlDecoder();
                case MimeTypes.APPLICATION_SUBRIP:
                    return new SubripDecoder();
                case MimeTypes.APPLICATION_TX3G:
                    return new Tx3gDecoder(format.initializationData);
                case MimeTypes.APPLICATION_CEA608:
                case MimeTypes.APPLICATION_MP4CEA608:
                    return new Cea608Decoder(mimeType, format.accessibilityChannel);
                case MimeTypes.APPLICATION_CEA708:
                    return new Cea708Decoder(format.accessibilityChannel, format.initializationData);
                case MimeTypes.APPLICATION_DVBSUBS:
                    return new DvbDecoder(format.initializationData);
                case MimeTypes.APPLICATION_PGS:
                    return new PgsDecoder();
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Attempted to create decoder for unsupported MIME type: " + mimeType);
    };


};
```

Basically it is overriding two abstract methods  **"boolean supportsFormat(Format format)" and
 "SubtitleDecoder createDecoder(Format format)"** declared in the base interface SubtitleDecoderFactory

But where to put SubtitleDecoderFactory.DEFAULT as a parameter in oder to get wrapped?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood from https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/4657#issuecomment-415739157, for your case you need to create a SubtitleDecoderFactory instance with following behavior:

supportsFormat call is delegated to SubtitleDecoderFactory.DEFAULT

createDecoder call uses SubtitleDecoderFactory.DEFAULT to create SubtitleDecoder instance and wraps it into another SubtitleDecoder instance (we will use anonymous class for it), which will delegate all methods except dequeueOutputBuffer to wrapped instance, and for dequeueOutputBuffer it will use your custom logic.

Your code may look like this:

```
public class mSubtitleDecoderFactory implements SubtitleDecoderFactory{

    @Override
    public boolean supportsFormat(Format format) {
        return SubtitleDecoderFactory.DEFAULT.supportsFormat(format);
    }

    @Override
    public SubtitleDecoder createDecoder(Format format){
        SubtitleDecoder wrapped = SubtitleDecoderFactory.DEFAULT.createDecoder(format);
        SubtitleDecoder wrapper = new SubtitleDecoder() {

            @Override
            O dequeueOutputBuffer() throws E {
                O resultFromWrapped = wrapped.dequeueOutputBuffer()
                // Do what you want with resultFromWrapped and return it modified
            }

            @Override
            String getName() {
                return wrapped.getName();
            }

            @Override
            void queueInputBuffer(I inputBuffer) throws E {
                wrapped.queueInputBuffer(inputBuffer);
            }

            // Delegate all other methods

        };
        return wrapper
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the "resultFromWrapped"  in "O resultFromWrapped = wrapped.dequeueOutputBuffer()"  what is refered to as "SubtitleOutputBuffer object"  in item    "4. In your SubtitleDecoder.dequeueOutputBuffer do the translation on the SubtitleOutputBuffer object returned by the wrapped SubtitleDecoder." at https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/4657#issuecomment-415739157

Comment: at https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/library/core/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/decoder/Decoder.java you can read dequeueOutputBuffer docs, which say that it @returns The output buffer, or null if an output buffer isn't available.

Comment: The  "new SubtitleDecoder()"  asks for implementation of abstract method flush () and release (). I am not able to figure out how to implement them, since these two methods are for the wrapper subtitledecoder itself, and can't get delegated to the wrapped subtitledecoder.

Comment: Just call wrapped.flush() in wrapper method as you do with other methods.

Comment: The "resultFromWrapped" is always returned as null. I just tested this:  O dequeueOutputBuffer() throws E {
                O resultFromWrapped = wrapped.dequeueOutputBuffer()
                return resultFromWrapped;
            }

Comment: I would like to know if  ardenit can give some hints to make "resultFromWrapped" returned as non-null object. help is greatly appreciated.